# Capping a toilet where flange is in cement

Tags: plumbing, toilet, cement

I have a couple of questions with the project I am working on.  A little background.  We currently had a bathroom right when you walked in from the garage.  We never use it.  Builder of house put it in as they build the house and lived here and used garage as sales office from rest of neighborhood.  I am in the process of turning it into a mudroom with lockers.

When a removed the shower there was a fairly large hole (2' x 2') in the cement where the drain went down and into the wall which is not surprising.  What was surprising is it seems the bulk of the area under the entire bathroom 5' x 6' is excavated.  There is 3-4" cement slab with iron over the entire area so structurally I am not worried just surprised me.

On to my two questions.

1. How can I cap the toilet drain.  I can do the shower since there is a hole but there is no hole for the toilet.  I am worried if I cut the flange out I will not have room for a cap because of the cement.  I also need to cap the water supply as that comes up from the bottom as well.  I am adding some picture so you can see the pipes run under the slab but they are out of reach to try and get to them there and hole is too small to crawl in and get to them.
2. I had planned to just add some gravel and then patch the cement hole so I could put flooring over it but now since the entire area is excavated I would have to get a lot of fill.  How can I patch that hole so I can add flooring above it?

Toilet Flange
[image: Toilet Flange]

Shows where hole is in relation
[image]

Shows where drain pipe goes up into cement to flange.
[image]

Shows pipe and water supply heading towards wall.
[image]

Comment: Do you ever anticipate anyone wanting to reinstate this in the future?  A later homeowner perhaps?

Comment: No.  Going to cap permanently.

Comment: You're going to put a new floor over the existing tile? Or remove the tile?

Comment: Remove tile and put in new tile.

Comment: My thought is, drop a half-bag of concrete down the pipe to block it, and trowel it off at the level so you can lay your new tile on top of it.